# WooCommerce conditional - display text if sort by date

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to find the sollution how to display text "Newest products" if user choose sort by date. Do I need to get page URL? There is: `?orderby=date` when I choose date sorting. Or meybe there is a sollution to do it with some WooCommerce variables?

The idea is to add `/shop/?orderby=date` to top menu and redirect user to the newest products. But I need to display some extra text like "See Our Newest Products" for better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to add your text.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', function(){
    if( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && $_GET['orderby'] == 'date' ){
        echo '<h3>See Our Newest Products</h3>';
    }
} );
```

The code goes to your active theme's functions.php.